Bad perfermance of conditional instrunctions
Test Case1:
    .text
    .globl  main                        // -- Begin function main
main:                                   // @main
.Lfunc_begin0:
    movk x11, #3, LSL #32 
    mov x0, xzr
    mov x15,xzr

.Ltmp6: 
    cmp x0, x11
    cset x13,le
    add x0,x0,x13
    sub x12,x11,x0
    tbz x12,#63,.Ltmp6
    ret

Test Case2:
    .text
    .globl  main                        // -- Begin function main
main:                                   // @main
.Lfunc_begin0:
    movk x11, #3, LSL #32 
    mov x0, xzr
    mov x15,xzr
.Ltmp6:
    cmp x0, x11
    b.lt .Ltmp7
    ret
.Ltmp7:
    add x0, x0,#1
    sub x12,x11,x0
    tbz x12,#63,.Ltmp6

Test Case3:
    .text
    .globl  main                        // -- Begin function main
main:                                   // @main
.Lfunc_begin0:
    movk x11, #3, LSL #32 
    mov x0, xzr
    mov x15,xzr

.Ltmp6: 
    cmp x0, x11
    add x0,x0,1
    sub x12,x11,x0
    tbz x12,#63,.Ltmp6
    ret

Environment info

Ubuntu 20.04
aarch64
clang 16.0

Result

Test Case1 take 17s.
Test Case2 take 14s.
Test Case3 take 7s.

Question
Test Case1 take much more time，is there any bug of cset？
Case1 has fewer branches and should theoretically perform better than Case2, but it does not.

This is gonna depend on microarchitectural implementation details of the hardware you're on, but why do you expect branches to be the only thing that matters? If you have a branch that always jumps to the exact same place for billions of iterations in a row, I would expect the branch predictor to make that have a negligible impact. Your cset, on the other hand, introduces a new register dependency.

Worth checking how the inner loop branch destination aligns with cache boundaries too - that can affect execution speed.  My hunch would be that Case 1 prevents the pipeline being used as effectively to maximise throughput because of the extra register used. Hardware branch predictors are very good these days so it isn't worth obsessing about them. You might also want to try loop unrolling to see if that helps or hinders. In the old days it was often a clear win but today it is finely balanced.

movk x11, #3, LSL #32 doesn't seem right - movk preserves all but the specific 16 bits that are being overwritten.  So you overwrite bits 32-47 with 0x0003, but bits 48-63 and 0-31 remain with their previous values, which are just whatever garbage may have been left there by the startup code.  Thus your loop is running an unpredictable number of iterations.  If you want exactly 3 * 2^32 iterations then use movz instead of movk.  Or better, just use mov x11, #0x300000000 and let the assembler work out the right instruction for you.

For a similar case on x86, see gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2 - a loop-carried dependency involving a branchless cmov vs. a predictable branch.  (Made worse by GCC making the loop-carried dep chain longer than necessary.)  AArch64 cset is a data dependency, branches are a control dependency that can be speculated (and later confirmed because the correct path is trivial to predict in this case.)

Thank you for your reply. It seems that cset has data dependency, which causes waiting in the CPU pipeline.
